# DB2 IBM - Sub query not reading aggregated column

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, subquery

I am not able to show the Total_Quantity_Order when using the Group by clause. When running the script below, I do not get any error but the column with total does not show up.

I am using the sub query to show the total quantity for the order.

The total quantity is the sum of the quantity of each order line. I've created a sub query because the group by statement will be so long due to the number of field selected.

```
SELECT
  A.ORDER AS ORDER, 
  A.LINE AS LINE, 
  *FIELD3*
  ...
  ...
  *FIELD55*
  FIELD56 AS QUANTITY
FROM TABLE1.A A 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT A.ORDER AS ORDER, 
    SUM(FIELD56) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER
  FROM TABLE1.A A 
  GROUP BY A.ORDER
) X ON A.ORDER = X.ORDER
WHERE A.ORDER = '140'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the outer select, you're getting `FIELD56 AS QUANTITY` but you alias the total (in sub-query X) as `SUM(FIELD56) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER`.

As far as I can see, you're not actually showing the TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER field in the overall select. Note that Field56 will still be reported as it exists in Table1 (e.g, it will be A.Field56).

It should be something like

```
A.LINE AS LINE, 
    *FIELD3*
    ...
    ...
    *FIELD55*
    FIELD56 AS QUANTITY,
    X.TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER    -- Added this row
FROM TABLE1.A A 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT A.ORDER AS ORDER, 
            SUM(FIELD56) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER
          FROM TABLE1.A A 
          GROUP BY A.ORDER
        ) X ON A.ORDER=X.ORDER
WHERE A.ORDER ='140'
```

Note that this (as well as your attempt in your question) will return 1 row for every row in Table1 which fits your WHERE clause (A.ORDER = '140') - not one row per order. However every row will have the total fpr the order included within it.

Answer (score 0):

If answer of **@seanb** didn't solve your problem, here follows my understanding:

The table **X** carrying the column **TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER** doesn't need a **JOIN** with table **A** because table **X** only carries the same fixed value for each line.

That said, query would be like that:

```
SELECT
    ...
    X.TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER
FROM TABLE1.A A,
    (SELECT SUM(FIELD56) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_BY_ORDER
        FROM TABLE1.A A
    ) X
WHERE A.ORDER = '140'
```